# PhpStorm Find & Replace regex

Tags: regex, phpstorm

I am horrible with regex and need to replace all functions that only have one parameter to be that one parameter. Aka delete the function call and leave the parameter if there is only 1 parameter, otherwise ignore it.

```
Some.functionName( OneParameter );
Some.functionName( OneParameter, TwoParameter );
```

So with the above Some.functionName( OneParameter ); would become

```
OneParameter
```

My only idea is something like:

```
^Some.functionName([!,])
```

So basically find all functions like that do not have a comma and remove the function call around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace: `Some.functionname\(([^,)]*)\)`

With: `$1`

`[^,)]*` matches any sequence that doesn't contain a comma or close parenthesis. So this will match the inside of the parameter list if it doesn't contain any commas.

Note that this won't work if you have nested function calls, e.g.

```
Some.functionname(otherfunc(1));
```

because the inner `)` will end the match. Regular expressions aren't good at matching balanced groupings.